Change VS Code Bulleted List Font Color in the Editor
My current VS Code theme is set to swap between solarized light and dark dependent on if it's day/night. I do that with this setting in my settings.json along with some Ubuntu OS tweaks:
    "window.autoDetectColorScheme": true,
    "workbench.preferredLightColorTheme": "Solarized Light", 
    "workbench.preferredDarkColorTheme": "Solarized Dark"

I've got a bulleted list in a markdown document in VS Code:
* Items
  * Item 1
  * Item 2
  * Item 3

The Solarized Light theme shows this bulleted list as orange text on a tan background in my editor. How do I change this orange foreground bulleted list text to a darker shade (better contrast against the tan background), and only have this apply to my Solarized Light theme? I don't want the Solarized Dark default colors to change at all.
If I change one of these workbench.colorCustomizations.json (full list here) isn't that going to change the bulleted list font color for both themes Solarized Light and Solarized Dark?

In settings.json, something like this probably:
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Solarized Light]": {
        "textMateRules": [{
            "scope": "markup.list.unnumbered.markdown", // see also markup.list.numbered.markdown
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#FF0000", // TODO
                // "fontStyle": "bold", // option style
            },
        }],
    },
},

Use the token/scope inspector to get scopes and current colour codes (run Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes).
